# React Native: Android WebView returns blank screen for some websites and some devices

Tags: android, networking, https, react-native, android-webview

I've got a working react-native app for quite a few months with a WebView directing to an HTTPS site.
This was all working great, but suddenly the WebView start returning a blank page instead of the HTTPS site.

From debugging, I've found out that:

- This happens only on my device (non of my users have reported this issue)
- Blank screen is returned for some websites, and for some it renders correctly. (e.g. google.com would render and amazon.com would return a blank screen)
- From debugging the WebView in chrome inspector it seems like every time a GET call has been made to one of theses sites (e.g. amazon.com) the call gets cancelled after 1 second or so.
- These sites are called, opened and rendered correctly on my android-chrome browser.

Seems like something in my devices is blocking some websites in WebViews, perhaps a settings, or an app. What could it be?

I'm using LG G4, tried on API version 19 and 23.

Comment: mention your device detail with api version

Comment: LG G4, tried API version 19 and 23

Comment: @grmmph did u fix the problem?

Comment: Same here, did you fix your issue ?
I have webview which works on iOS and not on Android.
However: "google.com" renders fine on both devices.

I dont see any Errors in console, its just blank

Answer (score 2):

It must be because of private SSL error in development mode. If you will see the console log in debug mode then you can see a line saying
`Failed to validate the certificate chain, error: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.`

If yes then just add a new prop which is not mentioned anywhere in the doc. The prop is `ignoreSslError={true}` which will force the WebView to load the website despite of SSL error.

Ex - 
`<WebView ignoreSslError={true} source={{uri: 'https://www.google.com'}} />`

Source: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/9680

Comment: It didnt work for me.
However if I tried to create native android with webview and ignore ssl errors like so.

 `override fun onReceivedSslError(view: WebView, handler: SslErrorHandler, er: SslError) {
            handler.proceed()
            // Ignore SSL certificate errors
        }
`
It works as expected.

Comment: Above does the same thing with react-native wrap. You can also use the third party wrapper https://github.com/ShivamKJJW/react-native-yunpeng-webview

Comment: Hi @if-else-switch I used this library and it worked for me! Finally, I've spent so many days to fix this. I cannot load URLs with SSL certificate issue in Android but I got no problem in iOS. I'm planning to use it for production but this library has no documentation or whatsoever. Is this safe to deploy in prod?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for me.

- First thing, check if there's something wrong with your certificate by using a tool such as this: https://www.digicert.com/help/

For me it became evident that my certificate was not trusted. In my case this problem could be solved by adding the missing intermediate certificates on the misconfigured server itself. Unfortunately, since I did not have the needed access, I decided to see if it would be possible to implement a workaround.

- Ultimately, I added a Network Security Configuration file and configured a custom CA as instructed here: https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config

Here are the details:

- My path looked like 
  /project_root/android/app/src/main/res/xml/network_security_config.xml after creating the necessary folders.

Here's what the contents of the file looked like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config>
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">example.com</domain>
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="@raw/my_ca"/>
        </trust-anchors>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

I replaced "example.com" in the above code sample my problem domain.

- Next I opened the problem domain in my web browser and downloaded the certificate to my machine.

In Chrome on a Mac you click the lock icon next to the domain, then on "Certificate" and drag the certificate icon to a local directory. This will transfer a DER encoded binary.

In Chrome on Windows you click the lock icon next to the domain, then on "Certificate", then on the "Details" tab and finally "Copy to File" bottom right. Select the DER version when exporting.

- For the next step I found that I needed to use OpenSSL.

To check if you have it intalled type

```
openssl version
```

If that fails you can install it on a Mac with

```
brew install openssl
```

For Windows instructions are here: https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html

- With OpenSSL ready, in a Terminal/CLI window I converted the file to PEM with

```
openssl x509 -in downloaded_cert.cer -inform DER -out my_ca.pem -outform PEM
```

- I moved the resulting my_ca.pem to /project_root/android/app/src/main/res/raw/my_ca.pem after creating the necessary folders.
- Finally in /project_root/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml I added android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" to the application element similar to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest ... >
    <application android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
                    ... >
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

oh，yeah,It runs successfully.

```
<View style={{ height: 150, width: 150,overflow:'hidden' }}>
            <WebView
              source={{ uri: 'https://github.com/facebook/react-native' }}
              scalesPageToFit={true}
            />
</View>
```