# Android WebView with react-native shows white screen

Tags: android, ssl, react-native, webview

I am trying to reuse react-native`s WebView to load a web site. Everything works on iOS. Android has stopped working after i updated SSL certificate. Worked fine with letsencrypt, but Comodo Positive SSL cert seem to cause problems.

WebView on Android now shows white screen (works with other web sites like google or facebook though).

Tried all I found on internet, but nothing seem helps.

Has anyone faced anything similar and fixed it?

ADD: Opening of the same web site in google chrome works just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting into debug of running Android app i found the problem cause  - Trust anchor for certification path not found. I wrongly built pem files not including intermediate certificates.

Comment: To load the website with ssl error you just need to ignore the SSL error. Look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47790072/3432566